# Rhythmbox 3.3 not working with Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus

Tags: rhythmbox

My Rhythmbox 3.3 installation worked like a charm under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
After updating Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 LTS my rhythmbox does not start anymore. If I try to install it with Synaptic I get many error messages.
What can I do?
Thanks for help

EDIT:

It seems there is some work going on in the background. Today I'm able to install Rhythmbox with Synaptic.

When I try to start Rhythmbox in a terminal I get:

Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: (File not found) Unable to init server: (no connection: Connection refused) - (Text within () is translated by me from German)

EDIT II

I got Rhythmbox installed and I can execute it, but Rhythmbox crashes after about 10 sec. so it is very useless.

Is there a error log?
And where can I find it?

Thank you

Comment: Can you add the error messages to your question? Also, can you run start Rhythmbox from a terminal, to see if anything pop up?

Answer (score 1):

First to be able playing MP3, MP4 and other media files you will need the multimedia codecs 
Type in terminal: 
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Than try to get Rhythmbox
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/rhythmbox`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install rhythmbox`

If for some reason you would like to uninstall this ppa, use:
`sudo apt-get install ppa-purge` 
`sudo ppa-purge ppa:fossfreedom/rhythmbox`

Comment: Thank you very much Benny! I will try to follow your instructions as soon as I have no result with Synaptic, and I will post my findings. I'm a bit hesistant to apply this changes because of the fresh installed upgrade to 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) and my very feable computer knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried rhythmbox every which way but it just chews up processing space and hangs in 16.04. It can direct play a music file but seems to get hung up on a significant music collection (I have ~10Gb). I've reluctantly given up on it.

To listen to my music in Ubuntu now VLC seems the best for me - it doesn't mess things up with internal formats for play lists or other complications so I can just play the albums (directories) and files without a problem. If I want a playlist I create a folder with soft links ;)